# How do I properly link text from an input field in HTML to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Im tryting to make a simple palindrom checker.

When Im testing in the console it works fine. However when I try to link it with HTML I cannot get it to work. I think this is due to an error extracting the text from the input field in the HTML file...

Javascript:

```
const str = document.getElementById('input').value;


function reverseString(str){
    let string = str.toLowerCase();
    let splitStr = string.split('');
    let revString = splitStr.reverse('');
    let joinStr = revString.join('');
    return joinStr;
}

function compare(str){
 if (reverseString(str) === str){
        document.querySelector("#answer").innerHTML = 'Its a Palindrom';
    } else {
        document.querySelector("#answer").innerHTML =  'Its not a Palindrom';
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="checkerContainer">
        <h1 id="heading">Palendrom Checker</h1>
        <h2 id="subtext">Enter a word of phrase!</h2>
        <div id="answer">Answer will output here!</div>
        <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Enter your word or phrase here!">
        <button type="button" id="submit" onclick="compare(str)">Check!</button>
    </div>  
</body>
```

When I change the `compare(str)` to output to the console it works fine:

```
const str = document.getElementById('input').value;


function reverseString(str){
    let string = str.toLowerCase();
    let splitStr = string.split('');
    let revString = splitStr.reverse('');
    let joinStr = revString.join('');
    return joinStr;
}

function compare(str){
 if (reverseString(str) === str){
        console.log('Its a Palindrom')
    } else {
        console.log('Its not a Palindrom')
    }
}
```

Comment: You only read the value from the input when the script loads and assign it to `str`. This just creates a copy of the value at that time and `str` doesn't get updated when the input value changes. You need to read the value when doing the comparison. There's no logical difference between your `innerHTML` example and your `console.log` example, so the latter shouldn't work any better, I think you're missing something there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to retrieve the string from the input at the time you're going to test it, so you have to get it in `compare`. How you have it now you're getting the input value before you type in anything.

```
function compare(){
  const str = document.getElementById('input').value;
  if (reverseString(str) === str){
        document.querySelector("#answer").innerHTML = 'Its a Palindrom';
  } else {
        document.querySelector("#answer").innerHTML =  'Its not a Palindrom';
  }
}
```